# Multiplicative absolute value

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normed-spaces, order-theory, absolute-value

The absolute value of a real number $r$ is defined to be the additive inverse of $r$ is $r < 0$, and $r$ is $r \geq 0$, where $0$ is the additive identity of the commutative group $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose we consider the multiplicative commutative group $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. We can play the same trick and define a "multiplicative absolute value" by $|r| == \frac{1}{r}$ if $r <1$, and $|r| = r$ is $r \geq 1$.

Does this function have a name, or a symbol? Moreover, does this concept  (usefully) extend to the level of some type of ordered commutative groups?

Comment: We can call it $e^{|\ln x|}$.

Comment: The "positive'  elements constitue the order cone.